# perforce get changes during certain period

Tags: perforce, p4v

`p4 changes @2018/09/27,@now` is working, but I want to know the change in certain directory like `//A/B`

`p4 changes @2018/09/27,@now  //AA/B...` and
`p4 changes //AA/B... @2018/09/27,@now` are not working, only returns all the changes from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one parameter:

```
p4 changes //AA/B/...@2018/09/27,@now
```

If you pass it as two separate parameters, first you'll get all changes matching the first one, then all changes matching the second.  What you want is all changes that match the entire set of restrictions.